# \mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/msys/1.0/opt/tcl/lib

Tags: gcc, mingw, tcl, tk-toolkit, mingw32

I am attempting to compile a simulator for Y86 code (http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/sim.tar) on Windows using mingw and msys, the simulator uses Tcl and Tk for a GUI that it has, so I first tried downloading the needed includes and libs for Tcl and Tk to build with, that didn't work, so I downloaded the source and built them in msys (http://wiki.tcl.tk/14828).

The issue I am having is that I keep getting the same error when running the make file,

> chrismeyer@MEYER-C /src/sim
>   $ make
>   (cd misc; make all)
>   make[1]: Entering directory `/src/sim/misc'
>   make[1]: Nothing to be done for`all'.
>   make[1]: Leaving directory `/src/sim/misc'
>   (cd pipe; make all GUIMODE=-DHAS_GUI TKLIBS="-l /opt/tcl/lib" TKINC="-I /opt/tcl/include")
>   make[1]: Entering directory`/src/sim/pipe'
>    Building the pipe-std.hcl version of PIPE
>   ../misc/hcl2c -n pipe-std.hcl < pipe-std.hcl > pipe-std.c
>   gcc -Wall -O2 -I /opt/tcl/include -I../misc -DHAS_GUI -o psim psim.c pipe-std.c \
>                   ../misc/isa.c -l /opt/tcl/lib -lm
>   c:\minGW\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5........\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/msys/1.0/opt/tcl/lib
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make[1]: *** [psim] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory `/src/sim/pipe'

Sorry about the formatting of the error, it got messed up a little bit.
The main problem is this line

```
C:\minGW\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lC:/msys/1.0/opt/tcl/lib
```

I am unsure why gcc cannot find the lib directory, it exists, I have checked many times.

Any insight into this issue would be very helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, was -l used for the file to link and -L for some extra libdir?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After taking a short look at the Makefiles in the sim.tar distro i would say your variables are not setup properly.

Try the following settings in your Makefile:

```
TKLIB="-L/opt/tcl/lib -ltk -ltcl"
TKINC="-I/opt/tcl/include"
```

Depending on the exact libs you have you might need to add some version numbers like -ltcl85 or so, but try without first.